# Is there a way to support a class without including the class in the assembly?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm developing a helper class to work with Lucene. It's meant to take an object into a factory and decorate the object with a method of indexing the object, adding an index strategy based on the type of object provided. The code looks something like this:

```
class IndexWrapper
{
    public interface IDocumentable
    {
        Document BuildDocument();
    }

    public interface IDocumentBuilder
    {
        Type SupportedType { get; }

        Document BuildDocument(object o);
    }

    public class StringDocumentBuilder : IDocumentBuilder
    {
        public Type SupportedType { get { return typeof(string); } }

        public Document BuildDocument(object o)
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new Field("string", o as string, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            return doc;
        }
    }

    public static class IndexableFactory
    {
        public static IDocumentable GetIndexableObject(object o)
        {
            return GetIndexableObject(o, DocumentBuilderFactory.GetBuilder(o));
        }

        public static IDocumentable GetIndexableObject(object o, IDocumentBuilder builder)
        {
            return new IndexableObject(o, builder);
        }
    }

    public static class DocumentBuilderFactory
    {
        private static List<IDocumentBuilder> _builders = new List<IDocumentBuilder>();

        public static IDocumentBuilder GetBuilder(object o)
        {
            if (_builders.Count == 0)
            {
                _builders = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                   .GetTypes()
                                   .Where(type => typeof(IDocumentBuilder).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsClass)
                                   .Select(type => Activator.CreateInstance(type))
                                   .Cast<IDocumentBuilder>()
                                   .ToList();
            }

            return _builders.Where(builder => builder.SupportedType.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType())).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    private class IndexableObject : IDocumentable
    {
        object _o;
        IDocumentBuilder _builder;

        public IndexableObject(object o) : this(o, DocumentBuilderFactory.GetBuilder(o)) { }
        public IndexableObject(object o, IDocumentBuilder builder)
        {
            _o = o;
            _builder = builder;
        }

        virtual public Document BuildDocument()
        {
            return _builder.BuildDocument(_o);
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering: Is it possible to include a default set of strategies for the class types users are most likely to see without including the libraries that contain those classes?

Comment: Curious, why don't you use ExtensionMethods for this?

Comment: @KingCronus I didn't know about Extension Methods! Thank you!

Comment: @KingCronus I'm curious, though: would extension methods be easier for someone using this class? Also, would they allow the same flexibility? I'm only just reading on them, so I apologize if this is a silly question. I'll try mocking some up and see what I can do with them. Thank you again very much! (Even though it doesn't answer the question of using types from other libraries!)

Comment: As far as someone using the class is concerned, they are just normal methods on the class which have been added from an outside source.

Comment: @KingCronus I'm worried about a user extending the class, though. I'm building it to make it easy for others I work with to use Lucene's indexing features. I'm wondering if it would be more logical for someone to implement IDocumentBuilder and write an index method or to have them write an extension method.

Comment: Have you ruled out defining a set of interfaces to expose the data then have your consumers implement your interfaces that would do things like get fields, get values, define indexes.  You could then let them pass in their own objects and act on them based on your interfaces.

Comment: @BryanRoberts I think that's what I'm intending to implement around this. The interface that exposes the data is IDocumentable (via BuildIndex()). My consumers will take IDocumentable objects and add the documents they create to the index. GetIndexableObject is intended to provide an easy means of supporting different types out of the box, allow others to write strategies for handling those types, and allow the method of handling types to be swapped in and out depending on how a user wished the object to be indexed. ...Does that sound correct, or am I completely misunderstanding?